# Arguments to change awk variables

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, terminal

Newbie at Bash Scripting.

List of Data:
Filename has date included "0310_Filename"

```
Hour     AM/PM   Game 1     Game2      Game 3

12:00:00 AM      First Last First Last First Last
```

I am trying to write a bash script that will allow me to pinpoint the name associated with a specific date and time and specific game utilizing grep and awk.  I'm able to narrow down all 3 names, but I can't manage to get the game narrowed down.

This is what works for the names per date and time:

```
#!/bing/bash

cat "$1"_Filename | grep "$2" | grep "$3"
```

command line input: `sh <scriptname> 0310 5:00:00 AM`

That will cat the correct file name based on the date, then sort via hour, and then sort via AM/PM.

This leaves me with the time and 3 names listed for that hour.  What I would like to do is add a final argument that can be either "game1" "game2" or "game3."

I attempted to create variables in the script to associate with awk delimeters, but the problem with that is that what ever I use for $4 ends up in the output...

Example:

```
#!/bing/bash

game1="'{print $3, $4}'"

game2="'{print $5, $6}'"

game3="'{print $7, $8}'"

cat "$1"_Filename | grep "$2" | grep "$3" | awk -v a="$'$4'" -F" " 'a'
```

Command line Input: `sh <scriptname> 0310 05:00:00 AM game1`

I have a feeling that I'm just failing at doing variables here, and don't fully understand how they work with awk...  What needs to happen is an argument needs to be passed into the script for the fourth variable, and that variable needs to dictate which awk numbered delimiter to print.  I hope that makes sense, and some guidance would greatly appreciated

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that variables should contain data, not code. So try to refactor to something more like `awk -v j=5 -v k=6 '{print $j, $k}'`. If you want more detailed help please post a minimal testable example.

Comment: ... also note that you don't really need cat or grep here - awk is capable of reading files and filtering ex. `awk -v hms="$2" -v ap="$3" '$1==hms && $2==ap {print}' "$1"_Filename`

Comment: `/bing/bash` is a typo, right? Why do you specify `bash` in the shebang, if you run the script with `sh`?